# How can I remove a file "--remove-files"?

Tags: linux

I tested:

> rm \-\-remove-files

but I am unable to remove it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`rm ./--remove-files`.

Note that `--` isn't interpreted by the shell, and by extension, escaping it with `\` will have no effect.

Answer (score 4):

rm -- --remove-files

Comment: Alternative: rm ./--remove-files

Comment: The double quotes are unnecessary.

Comment: Agreed.  Not sure why I typed them!

Answer (score 4):

```
$ ls -lah -- --remove-files 
-rw-r--r--  1 xistence  xistence     0B May  4 19:29 --remove-files
$ rm -- --remove-files 
$ ls -lah -- --remove-files 
ls: --remove-files: No such file or directory
```

So what you want is to use the -- as one of the arguments to rm, that means it stops processing getopt's, after that anything is taken literally:

```
rm -- --remove-files
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

> rm -- --remove-files

**Source:** http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-remove-strange-names-files/

Comment: This is not portable. Logan Capaldo's solution is.  Learn both.

Comment: Chas. Owens: Thank you! I did not know it. What does portability mean? Working in many OSs?